# Linq to Xml Get last Element - .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to fetch the last element according to it's name.

I know there is Last() method on .Net 4, but since I must work with .Net 3.5 how can I find it.

Example:
The xml used as log file.
My method signature: GetLast(XName xName), and returns the last element specified (ExecutionReport, Scenario, Function etc.)
I would like to get this element in order to add element afterwards.

This is the Xml file: [image: Xml file]

Comment: how about a .Reverse().First()?

Comment: Seriously? You posted a *screenshot* of the XML file, rather than the actual *contents* of the file? This is a programming website. You're asking a programming question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.Last()` exists in .Net 3.5 too.

You can write `parent.Elements("ChildName").Last()`.

Comment: Stupid me - I removed the reference to System.Linq. Thank you very much